# Authorizing the sandbox through VS code failure

Tags: sandbox, authorization, org

I keep getting error when I attempt to authorize my sandbox on VS code.

- The problem is: I follow the steps => ctrL+shift+P > SFDX:Authorized an ORG. I select test.salesforce.com page after setting alias for the org. I input my credential, I think it logs in too. However, as soon as I login -without seeing the org interface- , I see the following error:

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far: authorization ways (session id, project default, etc.), sfdx update, uninstall/install back VS code, turn off the enhanced domain, Extension pack, rebooting machine, sfdx-project.json update, kill nod.js in task manager, and many other things that I might have forgotten to list here. No hope!

I couldn't find and solution to my problem past 48 hours. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got a help form Salesforce. They recommended deleting everything in the folder of "C:\Users\username.sfdx", close and reopen the VS Code, then follow regular org authorization steps. It worked.

P.S: In the path where it says username, put your local username.
Thank you.